# how change position of element in .xml file from java code

Tags: android, xml

how change position of element in .xml file from java code
for example i need change position after some event

```
view.setX
view.setY
```

Perhaps for briefly example

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly. Do you mean, you have a XML like this: <data><x>1</x><y>2</y></data> and you want to change it to <data><y>2</y><x>1</x></data>?

That won't be something that you should ever need, since XML isn't usually ordered on elements. Can you clarify the scenario?

Comment: Actually if use AbsoluteLayout and placed different element on it's layout you you have ability to place this element by writing coordinate to code in .xml 
I wanna change this positions from my .java class(Activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a button is on an AbsoluteLayout this code will randomly move it when the button is clicked.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
      }
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Button btn = (Button)arg0;
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = ((AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams());
        params.x = (int)(Math.random()*200);
        params.y = (int)(Math.random()*200);
        btn.setLayoutParams(params); 
      }
}
```

Comment: oh i get it))
May be yo explain in few words what about Relative layout?